# How to disable FullCalendar onClick function for date control buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I hope someone has an idea for this. I'm using FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin. I added additional functionality to 'prev' and 'next' buttons to trigger events on other calendars. After user clicks buttons to go to previous or next date, I want that button disabled for 1-2 seconds. This is what I've tried.

Source code for 'prev' and 'next' buttons looks like this:

```
<td class="fc-header-left">
<span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-right" unselectable="on"> 
  <span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span>
</span>
<span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left" unselectable="on">       
  <span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span>
</span>
</td>
```

My code:

```
$('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
    var spinner = createSpinner();
    $('.fc-button-prev').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
    $('.fc-button-next').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
    $('.fc-button-prev span').onclick = null;
    $('.fc-button-next span').onclick = null;
    setTimeout(function() {
      <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
          $('#calendar_<%= doctor.id %>').fullCalendar('prev');
      <% end %>
      $('.fc-button-prev').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
      $('.fc-button-next').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');

      spinner.stop();
    }, 2000);

});
```

That doesn't work and each time user clicks on button new spinner appears. If user clicks on button 3 times in one second, three spinners would show up. Also, after timeout, calendar will jump three days front or back.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it disabled for 2 seconds using following code:

```
 $(function () {
            $('.fc-button-prev').click(disableNextPrev);
            $('.fc-button-next').click(disableNextPrev);
        });

        function disableNextPrev()
        {
            $('.fc-button-prev').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
            $('.fc-button-next').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
            myVar = setTimeout(function () {
                // your custom code goes here
                //.... 

                 $('.fc-button-prev').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
                 $('.fc-button-next').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
                 clearTimeout(myVar);

             }, 2000);
        }
```